# Extract Rows with Values >100 in a Variable Showing All Columns on MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, dataset, mysql-workbench, data-extraction

I have a large data set which has data like:

```
Cancer_Type    Age     Crude_Rate
Melanoma       20-24   30.5
Lung           70-74   212
Myeloma        55-59   101.8
Leukemia       35-39   77.9
```

I want to extract all columns with the rows that have Crude_Rates greater than 100 i.e. for the data snippet above what would be extracted is:

```
Cancer_Type    Age     Crude_Rate
Lung           70-74   212
Myeloma        55-59   101.8
```

I am trying the following code on MySQL Workbench:

```
SELECT Cancer_Type, Gender, Crude_Rate
FROM cancer.agescancer
WHERE Crude_Rate=(SELECT Crude_Rate WHERE Crude_Rate>100 FROM cancer.agescancer)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM cancer.agescancer)' at line 3
```

And the 100 in my code is underlined in red. I am not sure what I have done wrong.

Thank you in advanced for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change your query with,

```
SELECT Cancer_Type, Gender, Crude_Rate
FROM cancer.agescancer
WHERE Crude_Rate >100
```

Comment: Thank you so much - that makes sense!! :) I am a bit inexperienced with MySQL Workbench that's why couldn't figure it out :)